# Scala generic but unknown parameters

Tags: scala, generics

I'm having trouble defining a method using generic parameters in Scala.

Let's say I want a something like this:

```
class CollectionConverter {
   def convertListToSet(list: java.util.List[SomeType]): java.util.Set[SomeType] = {
     val s = new java.util.HashSet[SomeType]
     s.addAll(list)
     s
   }
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to make Scala understand that I don't know what SomeType is, just that whatever it is, the returned generic set will have the same generic type as the supplied list.  It complains that I haven't defined SomeType.  But that's the thing -- I don't know or care what SomeType is, it could be called YeahYeahYeah for all I care.

I don't want to use List[Any], and List[_] creates other problems, so... what's the right way to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what type parameters for methods are for.

```
def convertListToSet[SomeType](list: java.util.List[SomeType]): java.util.Set[SomeType] = {
   val s = new java.util.HashSet[SomeType]
   s.addAll(list)
   s
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh so close! So close.  Thanks VERY much, that's exactly what I needed.